# Не могу сделать фото на сайте вертикально

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Верстаю с помощью бутстрап 4 не большой сайт, хочу поставить свое фото, но оно отображается горизонтально, хотя на компьютере стоит вертикально, пытаюсь сделать фото вертикально с поощью свойства transform: rotate(90deg), но фото тогда вылазит из блока.

вот код: (помогите решить)

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <img src="img/photo-18.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6"></div>
            </div>


.container {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.header .container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.header strong {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.col-6 img {
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На компе оно у тебя скорее всего тоже вертикально. Попробуй его открыть в любом редакторе для того чтобы убедиться что положение фото точно такое, каким ты его ожидаешь увидеть на сайте. Bootstrap тут не при делах, и менять стилями ориентацию фотографии очень плохая практика. На крайний случай пересохрани фото повернутым.

Comment: Не получается, как бы я фото не поворачивал, на сайте оно остаётся не изменным

Comment: уверен что не перепутал директорию? открой в дебаге, посмотри на ссылку фото (дебаггер сразу и фото прогрузит). Посмотри на всякий случай на стили которые к фото применяются. Может где-то что-то уже перекрывается.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!